# Validate one field based on another Field in redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/), and my Component has several `FieldArray`. One of the FieldArray component generates table like shown in the screenshot. Here each row is a `Field` component including the checkbox. What I want to achieve is, if `checkbox` component on that row is checked, then only `price` field should be required.

I tried to solve this by using `validate.js` as described in [docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncValidation/), but since, this component has structure as:

```
<FirstComponent>
<FieldArray
  component={SecondComponent}
  name="options"
  fruits={fruitsList}
 />
</FirstComponent>
```

In my `SecondComponent` I am iterating over `fruitsList` and if length is greater than 1, then I render `ThirdComponent`. This component is responsible for generating the Fruit lists as show in the screenshot. Having some degree of nesting, when I validate with values, it has a lot of performance lag, my screen freezes until it renders the `ThirdComponent`. Each component has bit of `Fields` so can not merge them easily. Any easier way to solve this in elegant way would be helpful. The logic for validating is as follow:

```
props.fruitsList.map((fruit, index) => {
      const isChecked = values.getIn(['fruit', index, 'checked'])
      if (isChecked) {
        const price = values.getIn(['fruit', index, 'price'])
        if (price === undefined || price.length === 0) {
          errors.fruits[index] = { price: l('FORM->REQUIRED_FIELD') }
        }

      }
      return errors
    })
```

[image: Form Sceenshot]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The synchronous validation function is given *all the values in the form*. Therefore, assuming your checkbox is a form value, you have all the info you need.

```
function validate(values) {
  const errors = {}
  errors.fruits = values.fruits.map(fruit => {
    const fruitErrors = {}
    if (fruit.checked) { // only do fruit validation if it's checked
      if (!fruit.price) {
        fruitErrors.price = 'Required' // Bad user!!
      }
    }
    return fruitErrors
  })
  return errors
}

...

MyGroceryForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'groceries',
  validate
})(MyGroceryForm)
```